# How to get values of checkbox array in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I created checkboxes in form using javascript:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[]" />
```

When I check 1st and 3rd checkbox and submit the form, `Input::get("is_ok")` returns me:

```
['on', 'on']
```

Is there any way to get value as `['on', null, 'on']` or `['on', 'off', 'on']`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: weill i use laravel collective and set it to default 0 and if clicked then 1

Comment: you need to set a value attribute. When the checkbox is checked the name/value pair will be sent to the server otherwise it won't be. Unchecked values don't get sent by default.

Comment: @apokryfos when I add value like this `<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[]" value="1" />` I get `["1","1"]`. Unchecked values couldn't pass and I don't know which checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Then give each checkbox a different value so you can differentiate. There may be a jQuery solution when listening to the submit event of the form but there's no reason to add this complexity.

Comment: @apokryfos It is not exact solution but acceptable. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hey assign some values to checkboxes like `user_id, product_id etc` what ever in your application.

**E.g. View**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[]" value="3" />
```

**E.g. Controller**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['is_ok'])){
        if (is_array($_POST['is_ok'])) {
             foreach($_POST['is_ok'] as $value){
                echo $value;
             }
          } else {
            $value = $_POST['is_ok'];
            echo $value;
       }
   }
?>
```

You will get array of selected checkbox.

Hope it helps..

Comment: this is unnecessary IMO!

Comment: Same implementation as @apokryfos suggested you. At least you will get required checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a "good" solution to this (kind of).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[0]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[1]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[2]" />
```

(Forced indices here)

In the request:

```
$array = \Request::get("is_ok") + array_fill(0,3,0);
ksort($array);
```

This will ensure that (a) The checkbox indices are maintained as expected. (b) the gaps are filled when the request is received.

It's sloppy but may work.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is the best practice:

In your migration set that db table field to boolean and default 0

```
$table->boolean->('is_ok')->default(0);

{!! Form::checkbox('is_ok[]',  false,  isset($model->checkbox) ? : 0) !!}
```

and if you are not using laravel collective for forms then you can use vanilla php

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="is_ok[]" value="<?php isset($model->checkbox) ? : 0; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this for laravel 5

```
$request->get('is_ok[]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it might not be best practice, here is what I did first of all I send id of a specific model as a value.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="verify" name="is_varified[]" value="{{$bank->id}}" {{$bank->is_varified == 1 ? 'checked':''}}>
```

And in controller I added two query to update the field.

```
//handaling the issue of checkbox
Bank::where("user_id",$user->id)->whereIn('id',$request->is_varified)->update(['is_varified'=> 1]);
Bank::where("user_id",$user->id)->whereNotIn('id',$request->is_varified)->update(['is_varified'=> 0]);
```