# How to update model using checkboxes Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have list of checkboxes. How to update easy(add, remove) if checkboxes are selected or unselected?

Problem is that if checkbox is not checked, it can not be sent as POST parameter. In another case I need to get all checkboxes from database and compare with incoming values. If it is selected then to save them excepting others.

Comment: For post what method you are using ajax or form submit ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393059/how-to-get-values-of-checkbox-array-in-laravel-5 which has a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If I understood correctly) you want to delete rows whose ids are not in the user input.

Your checkboxes should look something like this:

```
...
<input type="checkbox" name="item[35]">
<input type="checkbox" name="item[36]">
...
```

…and in your controller, you should have :

```
$idsToKeep = array_keys($request->item);
SomeModel
    ::whereNotIn('id', $idsToKeep)
    ->delete();
```

Comment: I have situation when if checkbox is unselected I need to delete this from DB, I dont update them

Comment: Sorry. I updated my answer.