# Laravel - get all checkbox values from the Request

Tags: laravel

I have checkboxes in the HTML like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="models" value="ipad">
<input type="checkbox" name="models" value="ipod">
```

I am getting the whole form values in [Request](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) object, it contains a checkbox values like this:

> &models=ipad&models=ipod

I am trying to extract all these values in array, like this:

["ipad", "ipod"]

I've tried but did not work:

```
$request->input('models')
$request->input('models.*')
$request->all()
```

Also did not work:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="ipad">
```

Comment: What output do you get with the code you tried. Do you get any output? Or only one? Or is the key not even included in the result?

Comment: `name="models[]"` should work. If you rename all input names with `name="models[]"` it should show up with `$request->all()` and `$request->input('models');`

Comment: when you added `models[]` what comes in result of `$request->input('models');`? This should work.

Comment: Have you tried these solutions @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393059/how-to-get-values-of-checkbox-array-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="ipad">
<input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="ipod">
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, I tried this before but I was losing the value before it reached blade files. But works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="ipad">
<input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="othervalue">
```

If you have added `models[]` as array, then you can loop through the selected values like:

```
foreach($request->input('models') as $value){
  // $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose if you are using like this

```html
<form method="get" action="{{ url('/testing') }}">
  @csrf
  <input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="ipad">
  <input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="ipod">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
Then in response you get

Array
(
    [_token] => XhkdiOqbv24qhT4TnkT1liLm3GAyvTTt78vaDbBO
    [models] => Array
        (
            [0] => ipad
            [1] => ipod
        )

    [submit] => Submit Query
)


so finally you get array by $request->models

on print_r($request->models) you will get

Array
(
    [0] => ipad
    [1] => ipod
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="ipad">
<input type="checkbox" name="models[]" value="ipod">
```

and in your controller:

```
  $request->models
```